# Restrict user name to only one hyphen at the end of the name

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression for RegularExpressionValidator to validate a name.
At the moment it is `[A-Za-z'\ ]+` . Now the requirement is user name can end with hyphen, and just one hyphen and nothing after that.

So name can be john-, but not -john and not john--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` at the beginning and `\-?$` at the end should work:

```
^[A-Za-z' ]+-?$
```

Comment: No need to escape the hyphen (nor the space, come to think of it). Otherwise, +1 :)